# Why is argument type changed by different comparison operator?

Tags: python

When I was processing [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function):

```
def ackermann(m,n):
   if m == 0:
    return n + 1
   if m > 0 and n == 0:
    return ackermann(m-1,1)
   elif m > 0 and n > 0:
      return ackermann(m-1,ackermann(m,n-1))
```

I wrote wrong operator in 2nd `if` statement:

```
if m == 0 and n == 0:
  return ackermann(m-1,1)
```

But I got an error:

```
File "C:/Users/jacob/Desktop/think python/exercise 6-2.py", line 15, in ackermann
return ackermann(m-1,ackermann(m,n-1))

File "C:/Users/jacob/Desktop/think python/exercise 6-2.py", line 14, in ackermann
 elif int(m) > 0 and int(n) > 0:

TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()
```

Why is argument type changed by operator?

Comment: The code you included does not match this error message. How are you invoking your function?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/code/ackermann.py

Comment: Possibly you did not cover all the conditions and the function returns a None implicitly in your recursion.

Comment: @DaveQ Yes, that's what the two answers below say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the code that produced the error was

```
def ackermann(m,n):
   if m == 0:
    return n + 1
   if m == 0 and n == 0:
    return ackermann(m-1,1)
   elif m > 0 and n > 0:
      return ackermann(m-1,ackermann(m,n-1))
```

Let's step through an example.

```
ackermann(2, 1)
  # m = 2, n = 1
  m == 0: False
  m == 0 and n == 0: False
  m > 0 and n > 0: True
  return ackermann(m-1,ackermann(m,n-1))
    ackermann(m,n-1)  # the inner call
    ackermann(2,1-1)
      # m = 2, n = 0
      m == 0: False
      m == 0 and n == 0: False
      m > 0 and n > 0: False
      # None of the conditions matched, so we (implicitly) return None
      # because we didn't execute an explicit return
    ackermann(2-1,None)  # the outer call
      # m = 1, n = None
      m == 0: False
      m == 0 and n == 0: False
      m > 0 and n > 0:
        m > 0: True    # m == 1
        n > 0: error!  # n == None
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! really awesome your answer!!

Comment: The `ackermann` function in your answer is not the same as the OP's — where the second "if" is `if m > 0 and n == 0:`.

Comment: @martineau I got that from "*I wrote wrong operator in 2nd loop function `if m == 0 and n == 0: return ackermann(m-1,1)`*", which I took to mean that OP used the wrong operator (`==` instead of `>`) in the second `if` statement ("loop") originally, which somehow caused a type error that disappears if you use the correct Ackermann function (the first snippet).

Comment: Ahh...I see. Now the question (and your answer) makes more sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting you are not hitting either of the conditions and going to the end of the function causing an implicit return which is None.

Try returning some valid value at the end of the function.

e.g.,

```
def ackermann(m,n):
   if m == 0:
    return n + 1
   if m > 0 and n == 0:
    return ackermann(m-1,1)
   elif m > 0 and n > 0:
      return ackermann(m-1,ackermann(m,n-1))

   # Writing an explicit return to make sure we always
   #  return some integer and not None. Change this accordingly
   return 1
```

Comment: Return _what_ value at end of function?

Comment: I meant write an explicit non-None return instead of implicit None return.